# Ruby - remove underscores and capitalize

Tags: ruby, capitalize

Okay so I'm trying to remove the underscores, as seen in some of the holidays (for example,fourth_of_july). Then I want to capitalize each of the words.

Expected result: fourth_of_july > Fourth Of July

so this is my code:

```
holiday_dec = {

:winter => {
   :christmas => ["Lights", "Wreath"],
   :new_years => ["Party Hats"]
 },
 :summer => {
   :fourth_of_july => ["Fireworks", "BBQ"]
 },
 :fall => {
   :thanksgiving => ["Turkey"]
 },
 :spring => {
   :memorial_day => ["BBQ"]
 }

}

def all_supplies_in_holidays(holiday_hash)

  holiday_hash.each do |seasons, holidays|

    holidays.each do |holidays, supplies|
      puts "#{seasons.to_s.capitalize}:"
      puts "  #{holidays.to_s.tr("_"," ").capitalize}: #{supplies.join(", ")}"
    end

  end

end

all_supplies_in_holidays(holiday_dec)
```

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this one liner

```
str.split('_').map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
```

This takes a string `str` and splits it where the underscores are, then capitalizes each word then joins the words together with a space. Example

```
"fourth_of_july".split('_') -> ["fourth", "of", "july"]
["fourth", "of", "july"].map(&:capitalize) -> ["Fourth", "Of", "July"]
["Fourth", "Of", "July"].join(' ') -> "Fourth Of July"
```

Comment: def all_supplies_in_holidays(holiday_hash)
 
holiday_hash.each do |seasons, holidays|
   
   holidays.each do |holidays, supplies|
  puts "#{seasons.to_s.capitalize}:"
 puts "  #{holidays.to_s.tr("_"," ").split(' ').map {|word| word.capitalize }.join(' ')}: #{supplies.join(", ")}"
  end
  
  end

end

Comment: I actually did it that way instead of using the "&". What is the purpose of it?

Comment: You can use `&` when mapping over something if the map takes no parameters. It's the same thing as `{|i| i.capitalize}`, just shorter.

Answer (score 37):

In Rails you can use `titleize`

```
'fourth_of_july'.titleize => "Fourth Of July"
```

https://apidock.com/rails/Inflector/titleize

Comment: This is a Rails solution

Comment: I also like `humanize` as that only capitalizes the first word [rails api doc](https://apidock.com/rails/String/humanize)

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for a way to modify a string with underscores to be more class-name-like. Rails has [`String#classify`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/rails/String%3Aclassify).

```
irb> 'some_class_string'.classify
=> "SomeClassString"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion we can go through your nested hash, find all your keys and apply the change:

```
def key_changer hash
  hash.map do |k,v|
    [ k.to_s.scan(/[a-zA-Z]+/).map(&:capitalize).join(' '),
      v.class == Hash ? key_changer(v) : v ]
  end.to_h
end

key_changer holiday_dec #=>

#{ "Winter" => { "Christmas"      => ["Lights", "Wreath"],
#                "New Years"      => ["Party Hats"] },
#  "Summer" => { "Fourth Of July" => ["Fireworks", "BBQ"] },
#  "Fall"   => { "Thanksgiving"   => ["Turkey"] },
#  "Spring" => { "Memorial Day"   => ["BBQ"]}
#}
```

It's not exactly what you asked for (only realised after answering) but I'll leave this answer up nonetheless as you *may* find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
holiday_dec.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = v.each_with_object({}) { |(kk,vv),g|
    g[kk.to_s.split('_').map { |s| s[0]=s[0].upcase; s }.join(' ')] = vv } }
  #=> {:winter=>{"Christmas"=>["Lights", "Wreath"], "New Years"=>["Party Hats"]},
  #    :summer=>{"Fourth Of July"=>["Fireworks", "BBQ"]},
  #    :fall=>{"Thanksgiving"=>["Turkey"]},
  #    :spring=>{"Memorial Day"=>["BBQ"]}}
```

I used `s[0]=s[0].upcase; s` rather than `s.capitalize` because the latter converts all characters after the first to lower case (as well as capitalizing the first letter), yet the asker didn't say that was desired or if there could be capital letters after the first character of each word.